# Does the high-speed train from Chongqing to Chengdu depart from Chongqing or Chongqing North station?

Tags: trains, china, train-stations

I am travelling from London to Chengdu and noticed that the flights to Chongqing are much cheaper (often by several hundred pounds) than flights to Chengdu. I would like to fly to Chongqing and take the high-speed train to Chengdu instead. I have been trying to determine where the train starts from, for which I couldn't find much information online. It could be either Chongqing Station or Chongqing North Station. The only information I did find was on Wikipedia and seemed out of date:

- [Chengdu–Chongqing intercity railway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengdu%E2%80%93Chongqing_intercity_railway) - says that the line opened initially to Chengdu North railway station until renovations are complete at Shapingba in 2016. We are now in 2018 so I guess this is out of date. The "Railway Stations" section doesn't make reference to Chongqing North, and the map underneath shows it connecting to both Chongqing and Chongqing North.
- [Chongqing railway station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chongqing_railway_station) - says that currently the station is closed for renovations until 2015, relating to work on the aforementioned line. Again this is up to 3 years out of date.
- [Chongqing North railway station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chongqing_North_railway_station) - does not make any mention of the high-speed line to Chengdu, although it does say that it is handling most long-distance traffic until 2015 - again out of date.

I am not solely focussed on Wikipedia but that is the only online source I have found so far. Can anyone provide a more accurate website for this information and/or let me know the information for where to take this line from? Also any information on the timetable, would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search the timetable on the [China Highlights](https://www.chinahighlights.com/china-trains/) or [China DIY Travel](http://www.china-diy-travel.com/en/?source=L) websites.  At the moment it looks like most of the high-speed trains leave from Chongqing North.

Answer (score 1):

The linked information is outdated. The high-speed train departs from Chongqing North station (重庆北站), or Chongqing West station (重庆西站), or Shapingba station (沙坪坝站). The West station started to operate this January.

The Chongqing North station is closer to the airport. The Chongqing West station and Shapingba station are located on the outskirts.

You can check the timetable on [Ctrip](https://english.ctrip.com/trains/List/Index?DepartureCity=Chongqing&ArrivalCity=Chengdu&TrainNo=&DepartureCityPinyin=&ArrivalCityPinyin=&DepartureStation=%E9%87%8D%E5%BA%86&ArrivalStation=%E6%88%90%E9%83%BD&TrainType=&DepartDate=03-01-2018&searchboxArg=) in English.